# regexp value elements in array on Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, regex

in Python2.7.
I have an array with objects like:

```
[{"TEMPLATE_NAME": "HP_LaserJet_P2055dn_USB_S29HDY6_HPLIP", 
"PRINTER_INFO": "HP LaserJet P2055dn", 
"PRINTER_LOCATION": "Локальный принтер", 
"DEVICE_URI": "hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_P2055dn?serial=S29HDY6"}, 
{"TEMPLATE_NAME": "HP_LaserJet_P2055dn", 
"PRINTER_INFO": "HP LaserJet P2055dn", 
"PRINTER_LOCATION": "Локальный принтер", 
"DEVICE_URI": "usb://HP/LaserJet%20P2055dn?serial=S29HDY6"}]
```

It is necessary for any coincidence of the argument and the string to get the first object found in the array. Now it is done like this:

```
ArgInListFindNewPrinters = next(name for name in ListFindNewPrinters if ArgPrinter in [name['PRINTER_INFO'], name['DEVICE_URI'], name['TEMPLATE_NAME'], name['PRINTER_LOCATION']])
print ArgInListFindNewPrinters

>> {"TEMPLATE_NAME": "HP_LaserJet_P2055dn_49A71E", "PRINTER_INFO": "HP HP LaserJet P2055dn", "PRINTER_LOCATION": "Локальный принтер", "DEVICE_URI": "dnssd://HP%20LaserJet%20P2055dn%20%5B49A71E%5D._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/"}
```

The disadvantage of this method is that it looks for a complete match of the argument and the string, but I need any case-insensitive entry.
Example: `ArgPrinter = "LaserJe", ArgPrinter = "=S29HD"`

The main problem is finding any occurrences of a substring in a string.

===========================================================================
I found a solution, but it is not very practical because translation into a string requires a change in encoding:

```
ArgInListFindNewPrinters = next(name for name in ListFindNewPrinters if re.search(ArgPrinter, str(name), re.IGNORECASE))
```

If there are more optimal ways to do this, I will be grateful.

Comment: I found a solution, but it is not very practical because translation into a string requires a change in encoding:
`ArgInListFindNewPrinters = next(name for name in ListFindNewPrinters if re.search(ArgPrinter, str(name), re.IGNORECASE))`

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the target string and the searched string to lowercase to perform a case-insensitive search.

Use `if x in string` to match substrings.

There may be a way to do this more nicely, but this works:

```
ArgInListFindNewPrinters = next(name for name in ListFindNewPrinters
                                if ArgPrinter.lower() in name['PRINTER_INFO'].lower()
                                    or ArgPrinter.lower() in name['DEVICE_URI'].lower()
                                    or ArgPrinter.lower() in name['TEMPLATE_NAME'].lower()
                                    or ArgPrinter.lower() in name['PRINTER_LOCATION'].lower())
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem of register independence. But it does not solve the problem of finding any occurrences of a substring in a string.

Comment: Yes it does. `'ox' in 'fox'` is `True`. `'ox' in 'cat'` is `False`.